# ILS Frequency Assignment In Dual Nav Radio Setup

Tags: navigation, autopilot, ils

With a dual Nav radio setup (On autopilot panel) does the ILS frequency of the runway you're about touch down on need to be entered into both radios or just one? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ***need*** to be entered in either receiver.

If you want the ILS info displayed on the #1 display, enter it in the #1 nav radio. If you want it on the #2  display, enter it in the #2 nav radio. If you want it displayed on both, then enter it in both. If you don't need it displayed - perhaps you're flying a visual approach - then you don't need to enter it anywhere.

Some procedures may require a particular setup, but in the general case it's up to the pilot.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer as it's confirmed what I understood to be the case. A certain flight simulator states that the RWY ILS frequency needs to be entered into both NAV 1 & NAV 2 radios when flying an ILS/DME approach. I realise of course that the sim world and real world  don't always correspond exactly with each other @Ralph J